# D3.js sending path/link behing nodes/images

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I would like to be able to send the paths/links/edges behind the central image (the Marvel symbol in the example).

I'm using this example : http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/be2abfb3155a38be4de4

On startup everything is like it should be but when you click on the Marvel symbol, and then click a second time the paths/links open in front of the image.

I'm pretty sure the issue is with the click function but don't know where to go from there.

```js
var json = {
  "name": "marvel",
  "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/marvel.png",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Heroes",
      "children": [{
          "hero": "Spider-Man",
          "name": "Peter Benjamin Parker",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/54/spider-man",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_spiderman.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "CAPTAIN MARVEL",
          "name": "Carol Danvers",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/9/captain_marvel",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_captainmarvel.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "HULK",
          "name": "Robert Bruce Banner",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/25/hulk",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_hulk.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Black Widow",
          "name": "Natalia 'Natasha' Alianovna Romanova",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/6/black_widow",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_blackwidow.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Daredevil",
          "name": "Matthew Michael Murdock",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/11/daredevil",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_daredevil.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Wolverine",
          "name": "James Howlett",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/66/wolverine",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_wolverine.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Captain America",
          "name": "Steven Rogers",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/8/captain_america",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_captainamerica.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Iron Man",
          "name": "Anthony Edward 'Tony' Stark",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/29/iron_man",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_ironman.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "THOR",
          "name": "Thor Odinson",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/60/thor",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_thor.png",
          "size": 40000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Villains",
      "children": [{
          "hero": "Dr. Doom",
          "name": "Victor von Doom",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/13/dr_doom",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/drdoom.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Mystique",
          "name": "Unrevealed",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/1552/mystique",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/mystique.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Red Skull",
          "name": "Johann Shmidt",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/1901/red_skull",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/redskull.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Ronan",
          "name": "Ronan",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/49/ronan",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/ronan.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Magneto",
          "name": "Max Eisenhardt",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/35/magneto",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/magneto.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Thanos",
          "name": "Thanos",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/58/thanos",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/thanos.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Black Cat",
          "name": "Felicia Hardy",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/271/black_cat",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/blackcat.png",
          "size": 40000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Teams",
      "children": [{
          "hero": "Avengers",
          "name": "",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/68/avengers",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/avengers.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
          "name": "",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/70/guardians_of_the_galaxy",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/gofgalaxy.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Defenders",
          "name": "",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/534/defenders",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/defenders.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "X-Men",
          "name": "",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/71/x-men",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/xmen.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Fantastic Four",
          "name": "",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/69/fantastic_four",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/fantasticfour.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Inhumans",
          "name": "",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/1040/inhumans",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/inhumans.png",
          "size": 40000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

// some colour variables
var tcBlack = "#130C0E";

// rest of vars
var w = 960,
  h = 800,
  maxNodeSize = 50,
  x_browser = 20,
  y_browser = 25,
  root;

var vis;
var force = d3.layout.force();

vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

root = json;
root.fixed = true;
root.x = w / 2;
root.y = h / 4;

// Build the path
var defs = vis.insert("svg:defs")
  .data(["end"]);

defs.enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
update();

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force.nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .gravity(0.05)
    .charge(-1500)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .friction(0.5)
    .linkStrength(function(l, i) {
      return 1;
    })
    .size([w, h])
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

  var path = vis.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  path.enter().insert("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    // .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
    .style("stroke", "#eee");

  // Exit any old paths.
  path.exit().remove();

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  // Enter any new nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click)
    .call(force.drag);

  // Append a circle
  nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5;
    })
    .style("fill", "#eee");


  // Append images
  var images = nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      return d.img;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return -25;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return -25;
    })
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("width", 50);

  // make the image grow a little on mouse over and add the text details on click
  var setEvents = images
    // Append hero text
    .on('click', function(d) {
      d3.select("h1").html(d.hero);
      d3.select("h2").html(d.name);
      d3.select("h3").html("Take me to " + "<a href='" + d.link + "' >" + d.hero + " web page ⇢" + "</a>");
    })

    .on('mouseenter', function() {
      // select element in current context
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return -60;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return -60;
        })
        .attr("height", 100)
        .attr("width", 100);
    })
    // set back
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return -25;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return -25;
        })
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("width", 50);
    });

  // Append hero name on roll over next to the node as well
  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("class", "nodetext")
    .attr("x", x_browser)
    .attr("y", y_browser + 15)
    .attr("fill", tcBlack)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.hero;
    });


  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();


  // Re-select for update.
  path = vis.selectAll("path.link");
  node = vis.selectAll("g.node");

  function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {

      var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      return "M" + d.source.x + "," +
        d.source.y +
        "A" + dr + "," +
        dr + " 0 0,1 " +
        d.target.x + "," +
        d.target.y;
    });
    node.attr("transform", nodeTransform);
  }
}


/**
 * Gives the coordinates of the border for keeping the nodes inside a frame
 * http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492
 */
function nodeTransform(d) {
  d.x = Math.max(maxNodeSize, Math.min(w - (d.imgwidth / 2 || 16), d.x));
  d.y = Math.max(maxNodeSize, Math.min(h - (d.imgheight / 2 || 16), d.y));
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}

/**
 * Toggle children on click.
 */
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }

  update();
}


/**
 * Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
 */
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [];
  var i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children)
      node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id)
      node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:400,600);
body {
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", Consolas, monaco, monospace;
  line-height: 160%;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.node:not(:hover) .nodetext {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h2,
h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

header {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

a:link {
  color: #EE3124;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: #EE3124;
}

a:hover {
  color: #A4CD39;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: #EE3124;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<section id="vis"></section>
```

Comment: SVG elements are drawn depending on their order in the tree. When you collapse + expand the nodes, the new links are drawn in front of the old nodes, so they overlap. To see how you can change the order of the nodes in the tree, have a look at this answer: [How to update d3-force elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64970386/how-to-update-d3-force-elements)

Comment: Thank you ! I tried .raise(). But from my understanding it doesn't work images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `d3.selection.raise()` doesn't appear to exist yet in [version 3](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md);
2. If it did exist, you should apply it to the *parent*, not the image. The SVG structure is `svg > g.node > img`, but changing the position of the image inside `g.node` doesn't do anything - it's an only child. Apply it to `g.node`.
3. The other option I raised in the answer was to use two containers, a one for paths and one for nodes. Then, the order doesn't matter. I implemented that one below.

```js
var json = {
  "name": "marvel",
  "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/marvel.png",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Heroes",
      "children": [{
          "hero": "Spider-Man",
          "name": "Peter Benjamin Parker",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/54/spider-man",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_spiderman.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "CAPTAIN MARVEL",
          "name": "Carol Danvers",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/9/captain_marvel",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_captainmarvel.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "HULK",
          "name": "Robert Bruce Banner",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/25/hulk",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_hulk.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Black Widow",
          "name": "Natalia 'Natasha' Alianovna Romanova",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/6/black_widow",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_blackwidow.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Daredevil",
          "name": "Matthew Michael Murdock",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/11/daredevil",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_daredevil.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Wolverine",
          "name": "James Howlett",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/66/wolverine",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_wolverine.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Captain America",
          "name": "Steven Rogers",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/8/captain_america",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_captainamerica.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Iron Man",
          "name": "Anthony Edward 'Tony' Stark",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/29/iron_man",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_ironman.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "THOR",
          "name": "Thor Odinson",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/60/thor",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/top_thor.png",
          "size": 40000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Villains",
      "children": [{
          "hero": "Dr. Doom",
          "name": "Victor von Doom",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/13/dr_doom",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/drdoom.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Mystique",
          "name": "Unrevealed",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/1552/mystique",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/mystique.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Red Skull",
          "name": "Johann Shmidt",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/1901/red_skull",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/redskull.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Ronan",
          "name": "Ronan",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/49/ronan",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/ronan.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Magneto",
          "name": "Max Eisenhardt",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/35/magneto",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/magneto.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Thanos",
          "name": "Thanos",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/58/thanos",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/thanos.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Black Cat",
          "name": "Felicia Hardy",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/271/black_cat",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/blackcat.png",
          "size": 40000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Teams",
      "children": [{
          "hero": "Avengers",
          "name": "",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/68/avengers",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/avengers.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
          "name": "",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/70/guardians_of_the_galaxy",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/gofgalaxy.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Defenders",
          "name": "",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/534/defenders",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/defenders.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "X-Men",
          "name": "",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/71/x-men",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/xmen.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Fantastic Four",
          "name": "",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/69/fantastic_four",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/fantasticfour.png",
          "size": 40000
        },
        {
          "hero": "Inhumans",
          "name": "",
          "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/1040/inhumans",
          "img": "http://marvel-force-chart.surge.sh/marvel_force_chart_img/inhumans.png",
          "size": 40000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

// some colour variables
var tcBlack = "#130C0E";

// rest of vars
var w = 960,
  h = 800,
  maxNodeSize = 50,
  x_browser = 20,
  y_browser = 25,
  root;

var vis;
var force = d3.layout.force();

vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
var pathContainer = vis.append("g").attr("class", "paths");
var nodeContainer = vis.append("g").attr("class", "nodes");

root = json;
root.fixed = true;
root.x = w / 2;
root.y = h / 4;

// Build the path
var defs = vis.insert("svg:defs")
  .data(["end"]);

defs.enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
update();

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force.nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .gravity(0.05)
    .charge(-1500)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .friction(0.5)
    .linkStrength(function(l, i) {
      return 1;
    })
    .size([w, h])
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

  var path = pathContainer.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  path.enter().insert("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    // .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
    .style("stroke", "#eee");

  // Exit any old paths.
  path.exit().remove();

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = nodeContainer.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  // Enter any new nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click)
    .call(force.drag);

  // Append a circle
  nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5;
    })
    .style("fill", "#eee");


  // Append images
  var images = nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      return d.img;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return -25;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return -25;
    })
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("width", 50);

  // make the image grow a little on mouse over and add the text details on click
  var setEvents = images
    // Append hero text
    .on('click', function(d) {
      d3.select("h1").html(d.hero);
      d3.select("h2").html(d.name);
      d3.select("h3").html("Take me to " + "<a href='" + d.link + "' >" + d.hero + " web page ⇢" + "</a>");
    })

    .on('mouseenter', function() {
      // select element in current context
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return -60;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return -60;
        })
        .attr("height", 100)
        .attr("width", 100);
    })
    // set back
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return -25;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return -25;
        })
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("width", 50);
    });

  // Append hero name on roll over next to the node as well
  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("class", "nodetext")
    .attr("x", x_browser)
    .attr("y", y_browser + 15)
    .attr("fill", tcBlack)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.hero;
    });


  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();

  // Re-select for update.
  path = pathContainer.selectAll("path.link");
  node = nodeContainer.selectAll("g.node");

  function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {

      var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      return "M" + d.source.x + "," +
        d.source.y +
        "A" + dr + "," +
        dr + " 0 0,1 " +
        d.target.x + "," +
        d.target.y;
    });
    node.attr("transform", nodeTransform);
  }
}


/**
 * Gives the coordinates of the border for keeping the nodes inside a frame
 * http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492
 */
function nodeTransform(d) {
  d.x = Math.max(maxNodeSize, Math.min(w - (d.imgwidth / 2 || 16), d.x));
  d.y = Math.max(maxNodeSize, Math.min(h - (d.imgheight / 2 || 16), d.y));
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}

/**
 * Toggle children on click.
 */
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }

  update();
}


/**
 * Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
 */
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [];
  var i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children)
      node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id)
      node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:400,600);
body {
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", Consolas, monaco, monospace;
  line-height: 160%;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.node:not(:hover) .nodetext {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h2,
h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

header {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

a:link {
  color: #EE3124;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: #EE3124;
}

a:hover {
  color: #A4CD39;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: #EE3124;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<section id="vis"></section>
```